# Are XFS quotas and linux quotas part of the same thing?

Tags: inode, xfs, quota

I see there are two ways to create quotas, there is `xfs_quota` and then this suite of utilities like `edquota` and `repquota`. It seems all of these utilities can provide inode quotas. How does that tools relate to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XFS User Guide mentions that the generic quota tools work with XFS, but are unable to set project quotas on XFS.

[8.11. Generic Quota Tools](https://xfs.org/docs/xfsdocs-xml-dev/XFS_User_Guide/tmp/en-US/html/ch08s11.html):

> In addition to `xfs_quota`, xfs also works with generic quota tools
> provided on Linux. These tools include `quota`, `repquota`, `quotactl`, `edquota`, `quotacheck`, `setquota`, `quotaon`/`quotaoff` (enforcement only), `quotawarn`.
>
> The generic tools do not understand XFS project quotas.

The [RHEL 7 storage documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/xfsquota) pretty much states the same thing:

> Generic quota configuration tools (quota, repquota, and edquota for
> example) may also be used to manipulate XFS quotas. However, these
> tools cannot be used with XFS project quotas.